# AvalancheJS getUTXOS: couldn't unmarshal an argument

Tags: javascript, typescript, blockchain, decentralized-applications, avalanche

Hoping somone could explain what's going on here.

I am getting this error `Error: couldn't unmarshal an argument. Ensure arguments are valid and properly formatted.`

with this code, seems like something is wrong with xAddresses format?

```
const xAddresses:any = xchain.keyChain().getAddresses();

**const utxos:any = await xchain.getUTXOs(xAddresses)**
    .then(element => {console.log("sucess" + element)})
    .catch(Error => {console.log("Error in createSingedTX: " + Error)});
```

Answer (score 1):

Avalanche default [documentation](https://docs.avax.network/apis/avalanchejs/send-an-asset-on-the-x-chain#getting-the-utxo-set) and AvalancheJs [examples](https://github.com/ava-labs/avalanchejs#getting-the-utxo-set) are both uses wrong variables which is a buffer[] of your keychain addresses. Use string addresses array instead of buffer. It works!

```
const addressStrings = myKeychain.getAddressStrings();
const utxos = (await avmApi.getUTXOs(addressStrings)).utxos
```